# Run time error 3061 too few parameters expected error MS Access 365

Tags: ms-access

I have following VBA statement in submit button click event

```
Private Sub Command10_Click()
CurrentDb.Execute "Update products set Stock_Balance = " & Me.Credit & " where stock.Product_Name = '" & Me.ProductName & "' and Stock_Balance= 0  ", dbFailOnError
DoCmd.Close
 End Sub
```

Please help

Comment: Saving aggregate data is usually unnecessary and bad design. Calculate balance when needed. You reference two tables - products and stock - without JOIN clause. This should result in a non-updatable query which is probably true nature of error.

Comment: Try removing `stock.` from SQL.